# How to add explicit @Override in swig generated code?

Tags: java, swig

I would like to add an explicit `@Override` in the following swig code snippet:

```
%extend gdcm::Tag {
  int hashCode() {
    return self->MyCxxHashCode();
  }
};
```

Right now the generated java code does not contains the keyword:

```
package gdcm;
public class Tag {
[...]
  public int hashCode() {
    return gdcmJNI.Tag_hashCode(swigCPtr, this);
  }
}
```

while I would prefer:

```
package gdcm;
public class Tag {
[...]
  @Override
  public int hashCode() {
    return gdcmJNI.Tag_hashCode(swigCPtr, this);
  }
}
```

Comment: such macro (pattern) ... what in name of tool for generation ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is with `%javamethodmodifiers`, which normally is just "public", but can be co-opted to achieve what you want quite simply:

```
%module test

%inline %{
struct Foo {};
%}

%javamethodmodifiers Foo::hashCode %{@Override
  public%};

%extend Foo {
  int hashCode() {
    return 0;
  }
};
```